# Datatables - prepopulate search box

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to be able to store a list of common search terms, which a user can click and thus automatically filter a datatable.

```
$('#table').on('preXhr.dt', function() {
    alert('test');//$search
})
```

On http://datatables.net/reference/event/preXhr I saw this event handler could be used to do something before an AJAX call is made (which is perfect - as I could intercept the script at this point, add my prepopulated search term.

But I find that the first time the datatable loads, this event doesn't fire.

Any time I sort, etc it fires before the AJAX call.

But I really need to be able to access the search box in Datatables *before* the initial dataset is loaded.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify the initial search term in the dataTables options:

```
$('#table').dataTables({
    search: {
       search: initialSearchTerm
    }
});
```

where `initialSearchTerm` is the variable that holds the initial search term.

See [the documentation](http://datatables.net/reference/option/search.search)