# How to allow 'get' request to search Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I've installed https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack and love it.

But I find the documentation to be sparse, and the code is too vast/complex for me to understand thoroughly how I could do this:

I want to be able to bookmark pages such as **example.com/admin/contact/search/mySearchTermHere**, and I want that List of contacts to be displayed where `mySearchTermHere` is piped into the DataTables search field (and the appropriate results are shown).

When looking through the codebase, I found in `CrudRouter.php`:

```
Route::post($this->name.'/search', [
    'as' => 'crud.'.$this->name.'.search',
    'uses' => $this->controller.'@search',
]);
```

I'm not sure if that's even relevant to what I'm trying to enable (and I see that it allows only a Post instead of a Get).

How can I accomplish my goal (ideally without editing Backpack source code, which would then be overwritten next time I upgrade to their latest version)?

I sort of expected this feature to exist already, and maybe it does but I just haven't found out which URL to use.

P.S. I'm using these versions:

```
"backpack/base": "^0.7.19",
"backpack/crud": "^3.2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I anticipated.

In `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/list.blade.php`, within the options object of `var table = $("#crudTable").DataTable({...`, I added:

```
@if (Request::input('q'))
  search: {
      search: '{{Request::input('q')}}' //https://stackoverflow.com/a/28578355/470749
  },
@endif
```

Now whenever I browse to `example.com/admin/contact?q=someSearchTermHere`, "someSearchTermHere" is prepopulated in the DataTable, and the appropriate results appear.

<sub>Thanks to [Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28578355/470749) and to @tabacitu for the encouragement.</sub>

UPDATE: In later versions of Backpack ("backpack/base": "^1.0.0", "backpack/crud": "^3.5.0"), this code needs to go inside `dataTableConfiguration: {...}` within `resources\views\vendor\backpack\crud\inc\datatables_logic.blade.php` instead.

UPDATE: For Laravel 6.x and Backpack 4, `datatables_logic.blade.php` also needs:

```
$searchQuery = Request::input('q');
```

And in the javascript:

```
@if ($crud->getPersistentTable() && !$searchQuery)
    stateSave: true,//https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave
@endif
```

and

```
@if ($searchQuery)
    $('.dataTables_filter input').val('{{$searchQuery}}');
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The default way to do what you are trying is using [Backpack's filters](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/filters), which allow you to do exactly that - but will prepopulate the filter, NOT the DataTables search form. Take a look, I think it would be the fastest way.

If can only use the DataTables search for this, you can change the list view according to your needs. Just create a file called `resources/views/backpack/vendor/crud/list.blade.php`. Backpack will automatically pick that up instead of the one in the package. Copy the code from the original file and add the custom logic you need: after DataTables has been loaded, force search with jQuery.

Hope it helps.

---

To answer your first guess, the `search()` method is counter-intuitively used for returning all results, searched or not, if you're using [AjaxDataTables](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-full-api):

```
// ------ AJAX TABLE VIEW
// Please note the drawbacks of this though: 
// - 1-n and n-n relationship columns won't be searched anymore;
// - date and datetime columns won't be sortable anymore;

$this->crud->enableAjaxTable();
```

So no, it's not relevant to what you're trying to do. If you make modifications there, they would apply to each column row individually.