# Laravel Backpack how to bounce to exact match instead of showing just 1 result in table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

In my Laravel 5.7 app, I currently browse to URLs such as https://example.com/admin/contact?q=john@example.com using the ["q" param](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53471954/470749) so that I can search the Contacts table directly without needing to type into the DataTables ajax search field.

This works well except that I'd prefer it to bounce directly to the edit page (for exact matches of only 1 result).

In my `ContactCrudController` `setup()`, I have:

```
$q = $this->request->query->get('q');
if ($q) {// if there is an exact email match, redirect to the Edit page of that Contact.
    $matchingContact = \App\Models\Contact::where('emailAddress', $q)->first();
    if ($matchingContact) {
        return redirect(url('/admin/contact/' . $matchingContact->id . '/edit'));
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work because `setup()` doesn't expect a `return redirect()`.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#controller-middleware) in your controller's constructor:

```
class ContactCrudController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            if ($contact = \App\Models\Contact::where('emailAddress', $request->query->get('q'))->first()) {
                 return redirect(url('/admin/contact/' . $contact->id . '/edit'));
            }

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It almost worked, and then I added `parent::__construct();`, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`xhr` event of datatables.net](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr). You may use it to intercept the response from the server and redirect based on it.

I could imagine something like this on the server-side:

```
function datatableData()
{
    $q = $this->request->query->get('q');

    $contacts = \App\Models\Contact::query()
        ->when($q, function ($query, $q) { // apply filter only if present
             $query->where('emailAddress', $q);
        })->get();

    if ($contacts->count() === 1) {
        $id = $contacts->first()->id;
        return response()->json(['redirect' => url("/admin/contact/$id/edit")]);
    }

    return response()->json($contacts); // or whatever you return normally
}
```

And the following on the client-side:

```
var dt = $('#example').dataTable(...yourConfig...);

dt.on('xhr.dt', function (e, settings, json, xhr) {
    if (json.redirect) {
        window.location.href = json.redirect;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went with the other approach since it was more familiar.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the approach I went with (updated for Laravel 6.x and Backpack 4):

In ContactCrudController:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->redirectIfExactMatch();
}

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771897/470749
 */
public function redirectIfExactMatch() {
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $q = $request->input(self::Q);
        if ($q) {
            $contact = \App\Models\Contact::where('emailAddress', $q)->first();
            if ($contact) {// if there is an exact email match, redirect to the Edit page of that Contact.
                return redirect($contact->getContactEditUrl());
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    })->only('index'); //https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#controller-middleware
}
```

I'm using `->only('index')` to apply the middleware only to the `index()` function.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/53471954/470749